# Unit testing angular $modal.result.then()

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests for a controller and I stuck on testing `$modal`.
I am confusing how could I unit test code inside `newModal.result.then()`?

Here is the code:

```
 angular.module('myModule')
       .controller('myCtrl', function($modal){
           $scope.myFunction = function(){
               var newModal = $modal.open({
                   templateUrl: 'path.html',
                   controller: 'modalController',
                   backdrop: 'static',
                   resolve: {
                      message: function (){return 'some messages';}
                   }
               });
               newModal.result.then(function(type){
                   $scope.type = type;
               });
           };
       });
```

Here is what I have right now:

```
describe('Testing modalController', function(){
    var $scope,ctrl,$modal;     
    var fakeMsg = {
            result: {
                then: function(confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
                    this.confirmCallBack = confirmCallback;
                    this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
                }
            },
            close: function(item) {
                this.result.confirmCallBack(item);
            },
            dismiss: function(type) {
                this.result.cancelCallback(type);
            }
        };        


    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller,_$modal_){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('myCtrl', {$scope: $scope});};
        $modal = _$modal_;
    }));
   it("should open modal", function() {
        spyOn($modal, 'open').andReturn(fakeMsg);
        $scope.myFunction();
        $rootScope.$apply();
        expect($modal.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });    
});
```